# Getting Error 20 'NLog.LogManager' does not contain a definition for 'GetCurrentClassLogger'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, nlog

I am developing an application with windows CE, NETCF 3.5 I am using NLog2-All-Beta1 for logging, but it is giving error that Error 20 'NLog.LogManager' does not contain a definition for 'GetCurrentClassLogger'. If anyone knows the answer, please let me know I am new to NLog.

I tried with `GetLogger("MyClass");`
It is throwing an exception

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Screen' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'coredll.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Comment: @CharithJ Oh come on, he didn't accept answers on just 3 questions.

Comment: That was not working for me and I added comments and I did't get reply

Answer (score 1):

You won't get this method to work in Compact Framework because it isn't supported.

http://nlog-project.org/wiki/.NET_logging_API

> It’s also possible to use or LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger() but this feature isn’t supported in Compact Framework configuration, so if you want to support mobile devices you shouldn’t use this syntax. GetCurrentClassLogger is also quite costly because internally it uses the StackTrace class to get the name of the current class.

Comment: Yes, then How to use NLog for these type of versions

Comment: You can use NLog, just not this method.

Comment: Yes I am using NLog, I tried without this method still not working as I said previously it is throwing exception